# IE8 creates an extra floated div

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, css-float

I've been pulling my hair out for days over this one.

http://djembefola.com

In ie 8 there is 5 columns, even though there is only for 4 subcontentcols in the markup.

I've tried removing all the content of the columns and I'm now stumped.

Anybody have any ideas?